# React Native IOS DatadogSDK/Datadog.modulemap' not found

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I'm trying to build my React native iOS Xcode project but I'm getting this error:

> fatal error: module map file '/…/Debug-iphonesimulator/DatadogSDK/Datadog.modulemap' not found

[image: error screenshot]

After checking I found it searching in the other folder which does not contain (DatadogSDK/Datadog.modulemap') how I could let it point to the other folder in the DerivedData folder?

[image: folder location]

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of your image of an error message as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting).

Comment: You may want to try cleaning your project and/or deleting `DerivedData` and rebuilding. It would also be helpful here to understand how you've installed this Datadog SDK (ie manually, as a Swift Package, Cocoapods etc).